# Get different results with eq () or index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show only the corresponding elements in the order of the buttons, when I click on a certain button it shows only one element and hides the others, I got to do, I have 3 elements, when I press the first "eq (0)" it shows the first but also the last, when I press the second "eq (1)" it also shows the second but also shows the last, when I press the last "eq (2)" it shows what it should, it shows itself (the last one)! What's the problem?

```
$(".button").click(function(event) { 
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     var index = $(".button").index(this);
     $(".div-to-show").eq(index).css('display','block');
     $(".div-to-show").eq(!index).css('display','none');
 });
```

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve There is no way to see the HTML currently, and there may be a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of using `.eq()` and `.not()` with the index you have created.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".button").click(function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var index = $(".button").index(this);
    console.log(index);
    $(".div-to-show").not(":eq(" + index + ")").hide();
    $(".div-to-show").eq(index).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.div-to-show {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.button {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div-to-show">
  Div 0
</div>
<span class="button">Toggle</span>
<div class="div-to-show">
  Div 1
</div>
<span class="button">Toggle</span>
<div class="div-to-show">
  Div 2
</div>
<span class="button">Toggle</span>
<div class="div-to-show">
  Div 3
</div>
<span class="button">Toggle</span>
```

Reference:

- https://api.jquery.com/eq/
- https://api.jquery.com/not/
- https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of jQuery's [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) is [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/). Try something like this:

```
$(".button").click(function(event) { 
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
     var index = $(".button").index(this);
     $(".div-to-show").eq(index).css('display','block');
     $(".div-to-show").not(`:eq(${index})`).css('display','none');
});
```

Comment: Why are you using backticks?

Comment: @Twisty https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation